# How do I create a multi site web site in drupal 7 with diffrent admin panel ?

Tags: 7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting a user to a different home page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48055/redirecting-a-user-to-a-different-home-page)

Can anyone please tell me how to create a multi site website in Drupal 7 with diffrent admin panel?

I want to create a new website which has different front ends , links and different admin panel for each user login.

I want to do this for 4 different users.